# setTexture in three.js performance issues

Tags: performance, three.js, freeze, particles

When I am changing the texture of my mesh, on some computers, the application freeze for like half a second. I do that on 100 different mesh. On the Chrome profiler I see that the Three.js method `setTexture` is on top of the CPU usage.

The method I use to apply the next texture is the simplest:

```
this.materials.map = this.nextTexture;
```

This is working but I have no idea how to optimize this.
If use a particle system instead, would it improve something?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What functions within `three.js` are taking a long time?

Comment: Could you show more code? Are you reusing the new texture across all the meshes or does each mesh have its own texture?

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using 100 different textures?

Try sorting your objects according to texture, to minimize texture swapping.

Texture-change is one of the more expensive GPU operations.